# Dog who has escaped an animal shelter - name?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a dog who has escaped an animal shelter?

I was thinking *runaway dog?*

I'm sure there is a better word.

Comment: A dog without an owner is a *stray* but it might not have escaped from a shelter.

Comment: Incidentally, the modifier *runaway* is more often used for something (gone) out of control. *They are mysteriously injured in the tunnel by a runaway police horse* ODO: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/runaway

Comment: Loose: free from confinement or restraint; unfettered: loose dogs prowling around.

Comment: .....expounded?

Comment: @Kris: can you substantiate your claim that *runaway* as a modifier is "more often used" to mean "out of control" or running amok, rather than "fleeing"? My ngram searches suggest the opposite, though I would agree that the out-of-control meaning is quite common.

Comment: @TRomano "My ngram searches" -- interesting, where are they?

Comment: @Kris: Try: `runaway *` at https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: @TRomano https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runaway+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Crunaway%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brunaway%20slaves%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20slave%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20negroes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20inflation%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20match%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20horses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunaway%20servant%3B%2Cc0  What does that tell us?

Comment: @Kris: Not sure what you are referring to by "that". Could you elaborate?

Comment: Kris's link is here in its entirety: http://tinyurl.com/ptm9alz

Answer (score 6):

We often hear of "a runaway horse", "runaway children".  Google Ngram shows "runaway children" on the rise, since the second half of the nineteenth century, peaking in the 1980's. "runaway horses" peaked much earlier, and "runaway dog" has been on the rise since 1960.

- You are looking for a word that means "runaway dog".  I'd say that "runaway dog" is the best phrase for "runaway dog".

[image]

Comment: @Josh61 I've edited, thank you.[https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runaway+child&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crunaway%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brunaway%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRunaway%20Child%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRunaway%20child%3B%2Cc0] and [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runaway+child&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crunaway%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brunaway%20child%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRunaway%20Child%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRunaway%20child%3B%2Cc0]

Comment: @Josh61 Those are the graphs I used.

Comment: I always think that this sort of answer should be confined to a comment.

Comment: @Josh61 Ok, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use (figuratively) the same word or phrase that you would apply to people - eg "**fugitive**" or "**escapee**"?

Answer (score -5):

"Runaway dog" is fine and commonly used.

Comment: What's wrong with this one?

Comment: I've heard this word five times or so. Often enough for this kind of thing.

Comment: Nothing. The downvotes may be from before I deleted the extraneous editorializing. +1

Comment: See my comment at OP.